# System.SerializationException: Unable to load class:

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I have a scheduled class for which I'm getting this error.

> Apex script unhandled exception by user/organization:
> 0052i000001fdsd/00D2i0000003dds Source organization: 00D46000000ttrg
> (null) Scheduled job 'Scheduled Job' threw unhandled exception.
>
> caused by: System.SerializationException: Unable to load class:
> MySchedulable
>
> External entry point

This class is getting executed fine if I run it from the developer console. but on the scheduled one, I'm getting error.

```
global class MySchedulable implements Schedulable {

   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
   
      Date EighteenMonthOldDate = system.today().addMonths(-18);
      Set<Id> IdSet = new Set<Id>();
      For(CustomObject__c inv : [SELECT Id FROM CustomObject__c WHERE Status__c  IN ('Assigned/Transferred','Liquidated') AND Redeemed_Date__c <: EighteenMonthOldDate ]){
          IdSet.add(inv.Id);
      }
      
      List<CustomObjectB__c> CustomObjectBToUpdate = new List<CustomObjectB__c>();
      for(CustomObjectB__c corresMem : [SELECT Id,Deactivation_Date__c, Status__c FROM CustomObjectB__c WHERE CustomObject__c IN : IdSet AND Status__c != 'Don\'t Send']){
          corresMem.Deactivation_Date__c = system.today();
          corresMem.Status__c = 'Don\'t Send';
          
          CustomObjectBToUpdate.add(corresMem);
      }
      
      update CustomObjectBToUpdate;
      
   }
}
```

Comment: It won't affect the behavior, but you should really get away from using `global` on classes that don't need it.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the scheduled job and re-create it?

Comment: Well actually I deployed it from one sandbox to another and there also I'm getting same error

Comment: @AdrianLarson changing class from global to public resolved  the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your access modifier from global to public. Based on the comments, that fixes the issue.